# Do the Discovery Opening Credits Change in Each Episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In season 2 of *Star Trek: Discovery*, we join the crew in gradually learning more about

> an entity known as the "red angel".

Until episode 2x06, the opening credits contained a blurry rendition of

> the red angel

(right after the phaser schematic). In 2x06, the crew get a closer look, and it seems that for episode 2x07, the intro has been changed accordingly, as the blurry figure has been replaced with a

> schematic of the red angel's space suit.

**Have there been any other, more subtle changes to the credits in previous episodes?** (Maybe like *Game of Thrones*, whose intro is modified for [each episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM-YIENIVNM) to reflect the main places of action?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From time to time they have indeed changed the credits as elements of the story changed. The changes are not on an episode level for the most part. Memory Alpha [has this article](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery_opening_title_sequences), which shows no changes at all for Season 1. it does have this note for Season 2 (which you had noted)

> The Red Angel figure is replaced by a clearer Red Angel suit in the opening of "Light and Shadows", following Saru's observations in "The Sound of Thunder".

Season 3 offered one episode-level tweak for S3E10 (Terra Firma part II), which featured inverted background scenes on a blue field instead of the normal yellow. This was because

> the episode mostly takes place in the Mirror universe

Answer (score -1):

The 90-second opening credits for each season of *Star Trek:Discovery* are unique however nothing changes between each episode within that season. Ana Criado of [Prologue](http://www.prologue.com/) was the designer of the opening credit sequences. She was selected partially because she knew very little about Star Trek and was able to create something completely new without bias. She was given very loose instructions: "make it look like nothing any of the series had put forth before." After completion of the first season, Her team was nominated for an Emmy for Outstanding Main Title Design. Others on this team were Zachary Kinney, Nader Husseini, Francisco Sánchez de Cañete, Kyle Cooper, and Christian Antolin. One of the prominent pieces featured in the title was the all-important captain's chair. This displays how the constantly shifting command roles dominate the plot lines. The sequence was also heavily laden with Easter eggs for fans, if you look closely.

See a full review of the artistic creation of these sequences [at this link](https://www.indiewire.com/2019/08/star-trek-discovery-season-2-credits-sequence-1202168989/).

Comment: "The 90-second opening credits for each season of Star Trek:Discovery are unique however nothing changes between each episode within that season." - this sentence appears to be the answer to my question, but it still sounds a bit vague. Does it mean there is only one change between episodes within season 2, or are there any other mid-season changes (though not for *each* episode)?

Comment: There are many changes between seasons actually, not just one. Each is crafted uniquely. Nothing changes between each episode. So every episode in a season is the same. The article is very good if you like to review it. When you see season 3 it will have Easter eggs for the entire season

Comment: "So every episode in a season is the same." - I'm sorry, but I have to ask: Have you even read my question?